# Altbeacon spec and setup beacons

Tags: ibeacon, altbeacon, beacon

I want to know if I can setup altbeacon uuid, major and minor with altbeacon library for any beacon hardware that support altbeacon layout. I haven't seen this information in any place. Because of operational reasons, I need to set them up remotely, with open source software. All of them are proprietary. I am looking for an open source solution for set them up. Any help or information would be apreciate it.This question is related to altbeacon, because I couldn't find a non property solution for ibeacons.

Answer (score 0):

Altbeacon is 'old' and not used so much now. In any case, it sends out a URL, not unique id(s). You should instead look into Eddystone if you really don't want to use iBeacon. All beacons just use 'standard' Bluetooth advertising so there's nothing to stop you designing your own Bluetooth advertising payload. There's an [overview of advertising at BeaconZone](https://www.beaconzone.co.uk/what_are_beacons).

Comment: To clarify, the AltBeacon format does not send out a URL.  It sends out a 20 byte unique identifier space that is typically represented in the same 16 byte Proximity UUID, 2 byte major, 2 byte minor format as iBeacon for interoperability reasons.  Perhaps you are thinking of Google's URIBeacon format, which does send out a URL.  It has been replaced by the Eddystone-URL format which works in an equivalent way but is not binary compatible.

Comment: Sorry, no, Altbeacon doesn't send out a URL. The rest still stands - it's not used any more and you should probably look at [Eddystone-UID](https://github.com/google/eddystone/tree/master/eddystone-uid).

Comment: AltBeacon certainly is still in use.  I am currently building a system that uses AltBeacon at client request to deliver the measured power field and battery level (in the extra data filed) to an iOS app.  These fields are inaccessible using iBeacon alone.

Comment: Interesting. Why didn't they use Eddystone-TLM?

Comment: Eddystone-TLM does include battery level info, but it does not have a measured power field.  Another Eddystone frame like UID could be used to add this, but the Eddystone measured power field is a 0 meter reference vs. the 1 meter reference for iBeacon and AltBeacon.  Also, the identifier scheme for Eddystone-UID is incompatible with iBeacon, and iBeacon must be used for fast iOS detection as previously discussed.  Bottom line:  using AltBeacon as a secondary frame is a much simpler and more elegant solution than Eddystone for these kinds of cases due to its designed interoperability.

Answer (score 0):

The Android Beacon Library does not provide a SDK for configuring beacon identifiers.  Unfortunately this is not possible because every beacon manufacturer has a different way of configuring their beacons, and the mechanisms are  often proprietary and does not have a published API.

The open source AltBeacon standard is supported by a wide variety of beacon hardware manufacturers.  However, there is simply no standard way of configuring the identifiers.  You must follow manufacturer instructions.